# Windows 10 won't boot with bcdedit hypervisorlaunchtype auto

Tags: windows, windows-10, hyper-v, bcdedit

i'm trying to run a virtual Linux on my Windows 10 Pro Maschine using Hyper-V.
In order to  start that VM i have to enable the build in Hyper-V Hypervisor.
The problem is that as soon as i run "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto" Windows doesn't boot at all. There is the usual POST screen, after that the Windows Logo appears for a short period and then it blacks out and the POST Screen comes up again.

The only way to start Windows is to boot to safe mode and set hypervisorlaunchtype to off.

I copied my bcdedit below if that helps. 
I have a Intel Xeon E5-2670 CPU on a X79 Mainboard and VT-D and every other virtualization feature enabled.

Thanks in advance.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit

Windows-Start-Manager
---------------------
Bezeichner              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  de-DE
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {6b665eea-5425-11e6-9a30-fdda3dccc151}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows-Startladeprogramm
-------------------------
Bezeichner              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  de-DE
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {6b665eec-5425-11e6-9a30-fdda3dccc151}
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {6b665eea-5425-11e6-9a30-fdda3dccc151}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Off
hypervisordebug         No
```

Comment: I have the same problem years later...did you manage to get it working somehow?

Comment: Uh all that happend a long time ago. As far as i remember, i haven't go it to work. I bricked the Mainboard shortly afterwards and haven't had the same problem with the new Mainboard. The new one is a SuperMicro Serverboard with the corresponding Chipset. Are you are also running a X79 Mainboard with a Xeon. That might be the root of the problem.

Comment: Suffering this fate now trying to get WSL2 running. For some reason if you let the boot fail 3 times and then go to troubleshoot -> startup options -> debug It will finish installing the features and boot no problem but you'll have to do this on ever restart...

Comment: Such a shame, 4 years after and no resolution.... Can't get it to work even after all the reboots. Restore points are useless. And the sad part, it was a fresh install... Win 10 v2004