# Windows Won't Boot with "hypervisorlaunchetype auto"

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, bcd, hypervisor

I have the EXACT same problem as [Hypervisor BCD Boot Problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1128146/windows-10-wont-boot-with-bcdedit-hypervisorlaunchtype-auto) but it has not been answered.

I have enabled AMD-V in bios, I have checked msinfo for any problems with Hyper-V, reinstalled Hyper-V features. But nothing has seemed to solve my problem.

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {af5465df-cb23-11e9-bc19-cdc6a5fb078b}
displayorder            {a133f4df-0fef-11ea-b433-f82819b5a3ae}
                        {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {a133f4df-0fef-11ea-b433-f82819b5a3ae}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Hypervisor On
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {af5465e1-cb23-11e9-bc19-cdc6a5fb078b}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {af5465df-cb23-11e9-bc19-cdc6a5fb078b}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
hypervisordebug         Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {af5465e1-cb23-11e9-bc19-cdc6a5fb078b}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {af5465df-cb23-11e9-bc19-cdc6a5fb078b}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Off
hypervisordebug         Yes
```

I have been working on this for hours and any help is appreciated.

OS: Windows 10 Pro
CPU: R7 2700x
MOBO: ROG Crosshair VI Extreme

Comment: If you want an answer, you need to provide us with your boot configuration data, there are several answers to that question they are just deleted.

Comment: Edited to show bcd info.

Comment: What command are you trying exactly?  You have one configuration with Hyper-V enabled and one where it's disabled.  The current configuration has it disabled.

Comment: "bcdedit /set {a133f4df-0fef-11ea-b433-f82819b5a3ae} hypervisorlaunchtype auto" This should be the only different between the two

Comment: You are modifying the incorrect entry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101496/discussion-between-psaidiwd-and-ramhound).